# 2 Corinthians 1:12, "simplicity" or "simplicity of heart"?

Tags: acts, 2-corinthians

2 Corinthians 1:12, (DRB):

> For our glory is this, the testimony of our conscience, that **in simplicity of heart** and sincerity of God, and not in carnal wisdom, but in the grace of God, we have conversed in this world: and more abundantly towards you.

2 Corinthians 1:12, Latin Vulgate:

> 12. nam gloria nostra haec est testimonium conscientiae nostrae quod **in simplicitate** et sinceritate Dei et non in sapientia carnali sed in gratia Dei conversati sumus in mundo abundantius autem ad vos

Why DRB is not faithful to Latin Vulgate in this verse? Where the word "of heart" is not in the Latin Vulgate.

In Acts 2:46, the word "of heart" is present:

> 46. cotidie quoque perdurantes unianimiter in templo et frangentes circa domos panem sumebant cibum cum exultatione et **simplicitate cordis**

Acts 2:46, (DRB):

> And continuing daily with one accord in the temple, and breaking bread from house to house, they took their meat with gladness and **simplicity of heart;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Greek phrase in question at 2 Cor 1:12 is:

> ὅτι ἐν **ἁπλότητι** καὶ εἰλικρινείᾳ θεοῦ = that in **simplicity** and
>   sincerity of God.

The ancient MSS are almost equally divided as an alternate reading also exists, namely:

> ὅτι ἐν **ἁγιότητι** καὶ εἰλικρινίᾳ τοῦ θεοῦ = that in **holiness** and
>   sincerity of God.

For a list of which MSS favour which reading, consult UBS5.  Further, the Latin text is also divided.

The Jerome Latin text is:

> quod in simplicitate et sinceritate Dei = that in simplicity and
>   sincerity of God

The Clementine text says:

> quod in simplicitate cordis et sinceritate Dei = that in simplicity of
>   heart and sincerity of God (as per DRB).

This is yet another case where the Clementine text departs from both the ancient Latin text and Greek text in a quite inexplicable way.  It appears that the OP is quoting from the Jerome text rather than the Clementine text from which the DRB is translated.